# manipulating stored user object

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I'm using Passportjs to auth users on a angular + sailjs stack. When the user auths I'm storing an object of the user details (role, name, email) in a angular controller that is accessible by the other controllers. I may be off in my thinking, I'm new to the whole js stack, but since this object is stored by an angular controller it is visible / editable to the client. If so then they have the ability to change their role and make a request, which wouldn't be ideal. If my thinking is correct my question is how to disable them from doing so. How can I check against this object being manipulated?

Comment: While you might want to check roles, etc, on the client side to provide appropriate UI prompting, you should be verifying appropriate credentials and access rights on the server, not relying on the client to honestly/accurately present roles. i.e. don't rely on your client to prevent access to something, check it on the server.

Comment: Sounds like my concerns were correct. Looking at passportjs to verify user it says to use req.user, this is the request coming from the browser so I'm not sure this is the correct way to do this. Thoughts on the correct action to take with passportjs to verify user from server?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is all client side, which means don't trust anything. You can certainly store info in the controller, but it should be updated frequently.

In an app that I'm developing, I'm using a [`.resolve`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider) to verify the user's credentials on every route change. Everytime the route changes, a call is made to the backend to update the user info/credentials. This also allows to listen for a response from the backend saying that the session has timed out (which I then use an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#interceptors) to redirect them to the login page).

In general, if it's JavaScript, assume the backend will need to validate it. Client can't be trusted.